# Split string by commas only not leaving whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's suggest I have the following string:
`let cssValue = '20px, 40px'`

I wish to get the following array after splitting:
`cssValue.split(regex); // ['20px', '40px']`

But if the string doesn't contain commas (spaces only, i.e. `20px 40px`) the result should be `['20px 40px']`

My regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` doesn't consider comma. With this regex I'm getting `['20px', '40px']` regardless of whether the string contains comma or not. How can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm perplexed why you prefer a solution that requires two steps over one that requires only one simple operation.

Comment: I think this is a good conversation to have, @CarySwoveland - I love regex (I really do) but in this case there are merits to both the regex-based and the non-regex-based solution. I actually didn't mean to steal the thunder from Nina's solution (which was already the preferred answer when I posted my approach) - merely to provide an alternative to deploying the regex parser.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm sorry if it will sound like an excuse -- I thought stackoverflow.com would give me an opportunity to accept more than 1 answer. So, I like both solutions and do not think Nina's answer is worth than Rounin's one.

Comment: @DenisRybkin - I genuinely have no issue if you want to move your green tick back to Nina' answer. I think there is merit (as Cary points out) in deploying regex to carry out the intended transformation in a single operation. I also think there is merit in using built-in functions like `trim()` and `replaceAll()` to avoid starting up the regex parser when that's possible (which is why I wanted to post my answer alongside Nina's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split by comma and possible whitespace directly.

```js
const split = s => s.split(/,\s*/);

console.log(split('20px, 40px'));
console.log(split('20px 40px'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only intending to split-by-comma and remove leading whitespace, you won't need to use a regex at all, if you don't want to.

The string `','` will suffice, since, if you want to tidy up any leading whitespace afterwards, you can use `trim()`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let cssValue1 = '20px, 40px';
let cssValue2 = '20px 40px';

const splitCSSValue = (cssValue) => cssValue.split(',');
const trimElements = (array) => array.map((element) => element.trim());

console.log(trimElements(splitCSSValue('20px, 40px')));
console.log(trimElements(splitCSSValue('20px 40px')));
```